# No overload for 'MainFormLoad' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler' (CS0123)

Tags: c#

I've just started to learn programming in C# and I have a problem. I made a simple application (just a window with two buttons). One button starts another program and the other button shows this window again in 2 minutes (it's a sort of reminder). There's no X button, but it can still be closed by <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd> which I want to disable.

I've tried `e.Cancel = true;`, but I am obviously doing something wrong. What I did was doubleclick on the main window, then `void MainFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)` appeared in the code and I changed `EventArgs e` to `FormClosingEventArgs` and pasted the above `e.Cancel = true;` in there.

I am getting the following error:

> No overload for 'MainFormLoad' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler' (CS0123)

It refers me to this line in MainForm.Designer.cs:

```
this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.MainFormLoad);
```

Here's the whole code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Reminder
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Description of MainForm.
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            //
            // The InitializeComponent() call is required for Windows Forms designer support.
            //
            InitializeComponent();

            //
            // TODO: Add constructor code after the InitializeComponent() call.
            //
        }
        int duration = 0;
        void Timer1Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        duration++;
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo start = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        start.FileName = @"C:\ThisProgram.exe";
        Process.Start(start);
        Application.Exit();
        if (duration == 1)
            {
            Timer.Stop();
            }
        }
        void LaterClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        Timer.Enabled = true;
        Timer.Start();
        Hide();
        }
        void OKClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo start = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        start.FileName = @"C:\OtherExternalProgram.exe";
        Process.Start(start);
        Application.Exit();
        }
        void MainFormLoad(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
        e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the MainForm.Designer.cs code:

```
namespace Reminder
{
    partial class MainForm
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Designer variable used to keep track of non-visual components.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button OK;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Timer Timer;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button Later;

        /// <summary>
        /// Disposes resources used by the form.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing) {
                if (components != null) {
                    components.Dispose();
                }
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method is required for Windows Forms designer support.
        /// Do not change the method contents inside the source code editor. The Forms designer might
        /// not be able to load this method if it was changed manually.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(MainForm));
            this.OK = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.Timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
            this.Later = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // OK
            // 
            this.OK.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 253);
            this.OK.Name = "OK";
            this.OK.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.OK.TabIndex = 0;
            this.OK.Text = "OK";
            this.OK.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.OK.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.OKClick);
            // 
            // Timer
            // 
            this.Timer.Interval = 24000;
            this.Timer.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.Timer1Tick);
            // 
            // Later
            // 
            this.Later.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(425, 253);
            this.Later.Name = "Later";
            this.Later.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.Later.TabIndex = 1;
            this.Later.Text = "Later";
            this.Later.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.Later.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.LaterClick);
            // 
            // MainForm
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window;
            this.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("$this.BackgroundImage")));
            this.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Zoom;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(512, 288);
            this.Controls.Add(this.Later);
            this.Controls.Add(this.OK);
            this.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.MaximizeBox = false;
            this.MinimizeBox = false;
            this.Name = "MainForm";
            this.ShowIcon = false;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            this.TopMost = true;
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.MainFormLoad);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You need to handle the form closing event, not form loaded. [How to Disable Alt + F4 closing form?](//stackoverflow.com/q/14943)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Johnny Mopp. I did that now and there's no errors anymore, but unfortunately it didn't have any effect and I can still close the window by ALT+F4.